# Dell Laptop keeps Switching to Integrated Graphics for a few seconds - how to stop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have a Dell 5520 laptop that I use for a cycling app/game called Zwift.  The issue is that the game keeps freezing because the laptop periodically switches from the Nvidia back to the integrated graphics for a few seconds (1-5 seconds).... what could the issue be?

I have searched the forums and questions and made the following changes, none of which have resolved the issue:

- Set Windows power settings to max performance
- Set Windows graphics to max performance
- Laptop is always plugged in, never in battery mode (the laptop battery is dead, needs replacing)
- Nvidia control panel, have set both the global and the Zwift (specific game) settings to use the Nvidia, and power
  to max performance
- Monitored GPU usage and temps neither are too high
  when the issue happens
- I have run benchmark test and it never happens during these graphics tests
- I'm going to try disabling Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery

I don't know what else to try, it sometimes only happens every 10-15 minutes, but is very very annoying.

[image of GPUs from task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzJI0.png)

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Disabling-Integrated-Graphics-card/td-p/4455731

Comment: Unless Dell changed the chipset options in their software, switching from integrated to discrete had previously required a reboot after initiating the change via the requisite function key _(IIRC, it was possible to initiate the change without a reboot on Alienware laptops <2015 via Nvidia's control panel profiles, but I could be misremembering; however, AFAIK, it's always required user interaction to switch from one to the either)_. @Gantendo unless a user wants minimal battery life, disabling integrated graphics on a laptop is a bad idea since discrete is only required for movies and gaming

Comment: @JW0914 That is why you disable it, play games, and then enable it again.

Comment: @Gantendo the link you shared was about the user requesting how to permanently disable the integrated graphics _(third paragraph from the bottom)_

Comment: So I can disable the integrated graphics?  This may be the best option because I never use it on batter (battery is old and lasts about 10 minutes)....I'm a tad scared that if I disable the integrated graphcis then the laptop screen will stop working.
I've also just read something about a BIOS setting to stop GPU switching, not sure if that will help me, but will take a look.

Comment: @IanH No, you can't disable the integrated graphics - you can switch between integrated and discrete, but you can't disable the integrated graphics _(even if you had an unlocked BIOS - not UEFI, but BIOS - you still couldn't because the integrated graphics are the default option since it's apart of the CPU)_